# How to get values of all properties inside a class

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class SumsThirdDegree : ThirdDegree
{
    public SumsThirdDegree(List<ThirdDegree> allValues)
    {
        this.SumAllValues(allValues);
    }

    private void SumAllValues(List<ThirdDegree> allValues) 
    {
        this.X = allValues.Sum(x => x.X);
        this.Y = allValues.Sum(x => x.Y);
        this.XY = allValues.Sum(x => x.XY);
        this.XSecY = allValues.Sum(x => x.XSecY);
        this.XThirdY = allValues.Sum(x => x.XThirdY);
        this.XSecond = allValues.Sum(x => x.XSecond);
        this.XThird = allValues.Sum(x => x.XThird);
        this.XFourth = allValues.Sum(x => x.XFourth);
        this.XFifth = allValues.Sum(x => x.XFifth);
        this.XSixth = allValues.Sum(x => x.XSixth);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        var allProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var prop in allProperties)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Sum of {prop.Name} is: {prop.GetValue()}");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
        
    }
}
```

It is about `ToString()` method because I want to dynamically get all props names and their values. I don't know if it is possible to do that inside of the current class.

Comment: Change `{prop.GetValue()}` to `{prop.GetValue(this)}` to fetch value of property of current instance

Comment: Your class inheritance looks suspicious: `SumsThirdDegree : ThirdDegree`. It's similar as inheriting `Family` from `Human`.

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to do? `ToString()` is supposed to generate a default string representation of the object, not generate a scenario-specific string. You'll almost certainly want a *different* string in the next form, page or method. In any case, if you use a `record` you get a `ToString()` that contains all properties out of the box

Comment: What you attempt has a *significant* cost too. It uses reflection on every call to `ToString()` whether the values changed or not. The properties certainly haven't changed, so using reflection every time is simply wasteful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not issue, however `this` can be removed here:

```
var allProperties = GetType().GetProperties();
```

And set `this` object as parameter for `prop.GetValue(object? obj)`.

The whole code would look like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var allProperties = GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in allProperties)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"Sum of {prop.Name} is: {prop.GetValue(this)}");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

An example can be seen here:

```
class A
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var allProperties = GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in allProperties)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Sum of {prop.Name} is: {prop.GetValue(this)}");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and you can run the above code like this:

```
B c = new B() { Foo = 1, Bar = "2" };
string str = c.ToString();
```